# Slightly application of the space $C_b(X)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. The set $C_b(X)$ is the set of bounded continuous function. If $f\in C_b(X)$, there exist $C>0$ and $K$ compact in $X$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in X\setminus K$. I am trying to understand the existence of this $K$, where does it come from? Because $f\in C_b(X)$ usually means that there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in X$.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Where did you see this statement?

Comment: with no conditions on $K$ you can take arbitrary $K$ and as $C$ the constant such that $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in X$, are you sure you got the statement right?

Comment: Your statement as stated is trivial, take $K = \varnothing$ and $C$ and bound on $f.$ Maybe you want to say something about $f$ vanishing at infinity, like for such $f$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $K$ compact such that $|f| < \varepsilon$ outside $K$ (this is the definition though)?

Answer (score 1):

You (or your source) seems to confuse two (or more) notions: what you state last, i.e.

$$\exists C>0: \forall x \in X: |f(x)| \le C\tag{1}$$

is what I consider the definition of a function in $C_b(X)$, a bounded function (that is also continuous).

There also is a common notion of compactly supported continuous function which states that ($f$ is continuous and):

$$\exists K \subseteq X \text{ compact } \forall x \in X\setminus K: f(x)=0\tag{2}$$

and whose set is denoted by $C_c(X)$ in some texts.

There are also functions said "to vanish at infinity" (see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_vanishing_at_infinity) e.g.) namely when

$$\forall \varepsilon>0: \exists K \subseteq X \text{ compact }: \forall x \in X\setminus K: |f(x)| \le \varepsilon\tag{3}$$

and the continuous ones are denotes $C_0(X)$ and form a superset of both $C_c(X)$ and also a subset of $C_b(X)$.

All are commonly studied Banach spaces in the context of locally compact Hausdorff spaces. $C_b(X)$ is also denoted $C^\ast(X)$ and is an interesting ring (for the right spaces $X$..) in topological theory.

What your source describes is more like "bounded at infinity" as opposed to vanishing at infinity; As stated now, we can just take $K=\emptyset$ for any bounded continuous $f$ anyway (and as all functions in the set are bounded (they're already bounded outside $K$ and by continuity on $K$ too..) we just get back all bounded functions. So it just equals definition $(1)$ for continuous functions.